# Kernel version is still 4.15, after upgrading to 5.1 Hera

Tags: updates, kernel, release-hera

I've updated my system, but it didn't update the kernel. Please see the output of my commands:

```
loathe@elementaryos ~> lsb_release --all 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1 Hera
Release:    5.1
Codename:   hera
loathe@elementaryos ~> uname -r
4.15.0-72-generic
```

After running "apt update", it says my packages are up to date. How can I update the kernel, and any other packages if they should be updated too(didn't check other packages besides the kernel)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [announcement blog post](https://blog.elementary.io/introducing-elementary-os-5-1-hera/):

> …if you’re on an existing Juno install and would like or need the improved hardware support, you can install it from Terminal with the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering why they didn't release it for the old users. I know elementary OS is not rolling release but, seems odd.

Comment: Good question but it ended up working out for me as the 18.04 HWE causes issues when I come out of suspend while connected to an HDMI monitor on my Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

For Elementary OS 5.1 you need to update your kernel like this

**Check your kernel version**

```
$ uname -r                                                                            
4.15.0-72-generic
```

**Update your kernel**

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-hwe-doc-5.0.0 | linux-hwe-source-5.0.0 linux-hwe-tools xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi firmware-amd-graphics xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
  firmware-misc-nonfree
Recommended packages:
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy
  xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 17 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 69,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 331 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
...
...
...
```

**reboot your Elementary OS**

```
$ reboot
```

**check your kernel version**

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic
```

***Here the result with about :***

[image: elementaryos_about]